# External File currently in use issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, streamwriter

I'm building a register program for college work using the c# console application within visual studio, and I've stumbled upon an issue with one of my external files. Apparently it's currently being used by another program and I can't find how to fix it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Class_Register_V1._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, classSize, weekCount, periodsPerWeek, counter, count, Value, input2, Outcome;
            string answer, input, test;
            Value = 0;
            Outcome = 0;
            StreamReader Size = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Dannys\Desktop\RegisterArraySize.txt");
            count = Convert.ToInt32(Size.ReadLine());
            Size.Close();
            int newV = count - 1;
            int[] myListOfUsername = new int[count];
            StreamReader LogIn = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Dannys\Desktop\RegisterLogIn.txt");
            for (int NewA = 0; NewA < count; NewA++)
            {
                myListOfUsername[NewA] = Convert.ToInt32(LogIn.ReadLine());
            }
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to CodeTown's ClassLogIn.");
            Console.WriteLine("1. login\n2. Register\n3. Exit");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            input2 = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            Console.Clear();
            switch (input)
            {
                case "1":
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your login");
                        Value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                        for (int NewB = 0; NewB < count; NewB++)
                        {
                            if (Value == myListOfUsername[NewB])
                            {
                                Outcome = 1;
                                Console.Clear();
                            }
                        }
                        if (Outcome == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Login not recognised");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            Console.Clear();
                        }
                    } while (Outcome == 0);
                    break;

                case "2":
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Create 6 number Login ID\ni.e. 936548");
                            test = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (test.Length > 6)
                            {
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("The login you used was too long!");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }
                            if (test.Length < 6)
                            {
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("The login you used was too short!");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }
                            Console.Clear();
                        } while (test.Length != 6);

                        count++;
                        newV = count - 1;
                        int[] ListOfUsername = new int[count];
                        StreamReader LogInCreate = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Dannys\Desktop\RegisterLogIn.txt");
                        for (int NewC = 0; NewC < count; NewC++)
                        {
                            ListOfUsername[NewC] = Convert.ToInt32(LogIn.ReadLine());
                        }
                        ListOfUsername[newV] = Convert.ToInt32(test);
                        Console.WriteLine("Login will be registered once ClassLogIn has been restarted.\nWelcome abord!");
                        StreamWriter array = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dannys\Desktop\RegisterArraySize.txt");
                        array.WriteLine(count);
                        array.Close();
                        StreamWriter LogInWrite = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dannys\Desktop\RegisterLogIn.txt");
                        for (int NewD = 0; NewD < count; NewD++)
                        {
                            LogInWrite.WriteLine(ListOfUsername[NewD]);
                        }
                        LogInWrite.Close();
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                    break;

                case "3":
                    {

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the snippet that is creating errors:

```
StreamWriter LogInWrite = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dannys\Desktop\RegisterLogIn.txt");
for (int NewD = 0; NewD < count; NewD++)
{
    LogInWrite.WriteLine(ListOfUsername[NewD]);
}
LogInWrite.Close();
```

My only thought for what could be causing this would be that you can only use WriteLine once per file as it doesn't actually write a line like it would in a console, so I'd need to create a new file for every username. If this is in fact the issue, is using a loop for creating a potentially endless list of 6 digit txt files my only option?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 2 stream objects. You aren't closing or disposing of the first one which is accessing the exact same file as your second stream object. You need to wrap your Stream object calls in using statements so they automatically Dispose and release any holds they have on files.

Comment: From what Militello just posted, I now understand what you meant! thank you

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest the "using" statement also when you write the file.

```
            // Write each directory name to a file.
            using (StreamWriter LogInWrite = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dannys\Desktop\RegisterLogIn.txt"))
            {
               for (int NewD = 0; NewD < count; NewD++)
                  LogInWrite.WriteLine(ListOfUsername[NewD]);
            }
```

In this way your writer will always release the file/resource.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: I've implemented the using code, but it still says it's in use. Could it be that you can only writeline to a txt file once? and the repeated action of WriteLine is what's showing up as "already in use"

Comment: I don't think so.
This is the code used in the MSDN example. As you can see, it does pretty much the same thing you do.

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("CDriveDirs.txt")){
                foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in cDirs)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(dir.Name);

                }
    }

Perhaps there is some hidden "debug" process that you interrupt while the "using" statement was not in place which keep the file in use.